# Should 2 posts be closed as duplicate to each other

Tags: discussion

This is the post in question

[Inserting a (jpg) picture into a cell in Microsoft Excel 2007](https://superuser.com/questions/117623/inserting-a-jpg-picture-into-a-cell-in-microsoft-excel-2007)

If you click on the duplicate you get taken to [How do I load external images into Excel?](https://superuser.com/questions/584650/how-do-i-load-external-images-into-excel)

If you click on that, you are returned to the first link.

This means, I think, that [Inserting a (jpg) picture into a cell in Microsoft Excel 2007](https://superuser.com/questions/117623/inserting-a-jpg-picture-into-a-cell-in-microsoft-excel-2007) should be re-opened; it's not a duplicate if it came first?

The problem is, I'm trying to close [Excel - Filling images using a reference image](https://superuser.com/questions/767203/excel-filling-images-using-a-reference-image) as a duplicate to the above but I can't:

[image]

So, I guess this just means the system can't handle this and therefore the duplicate rules that site applies can't be applied in this case?

Is this a bug in the sense we can't close posts like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, two posts should never be closed as duplicates of each other.

I reopened [Inserting a (jpg) picture into a cell in Microsoft Excel 2007](https://superuser.com/questions/117623/inserting-a-jpg-picture-into-a-cell-in-microsoft-excel-2007). No idea how this was possible in the first place.

Comment: Cool, again, thank you :)